# blank space on top and left of the page while developing frontend

Tags: html, css, django

I am building an application in Django and for writing templates I am using HTML/CSS, now there is some weird white space I am encountering on the top and left side of the page which does not go, no matter what I try as shown below

[image]

now here are my css files

> base.css

```
.navbar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    background-color: #333;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    z-index: -1;
}

.navbar-brand img {
    max-height: 40px;
}

.navbar-menu ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
}

.navbar-menu li {
    margin: 0 10px;
}

.navbar-menu li a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.navbar-user img {
    max-height: 30px;
}
```

> and home.css

```
.home-video {
    position: relative;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: -1;
}

#bg-video {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    object-fit: cover;
}

.home-content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    text-align: center;
}

.home-content h1 {
    font-size: 3rem;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    color: white;
}

.home-content p {
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    color: white;
}

.btn {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    background-color: #333;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
}

.btn:hover {
    background-color: #555;
}
```

I have tries doing almost everything and cannot find what I am doing wrong, please help me. Thanks.

Comment: In your browser's development/debugging tools, use the DOM Explorer to highlight and find the element producing the whitespace and the style rules applied to that element.  Are those rules different from what you expect?  Can you update the question to a [mcve] as a [runnable code snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/328193) which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: @David on inspecting, there is a margin of 8px in body tag, but even after setting both margin and padding to 0 in css, there is nothing changing

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: {there is a margin of 8px in body tag, but even after setting both margin and padding to 0 in css, there is nothing changing } how us your code. It should work.

Answer (score 1):

Guys I found the solution, I was using Google cloud storage in this project, so I had to run python manage.py collectstatic to show the changes live. Sorry for not providing that code.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code.

```css
body{
    margin: 0px !important;
    padding: 0px !important;
}
```